# setup spamassassin not all parameters are displayed as a result of the check

Tags: spamassassin

good afternoon, I'm faced with the task of configuring spamassassin (I haven't set it up before). I need to get values like in [www.mail-tester.com](http://www.mail-tester.com) (DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,DKIM_VALID_EF,FSL_BULK_SIG,HTML_MESSAGE,HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,PYZOR_CHECK,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2,SPF_HELO_NONE,SPF_PASS ) but no matter what settings I tried, all the fields still don't come. I will be very glad to receive any advice or a link to any article.

my /etc/spamassassin/local.cf

```
rewrite_header Subject [***** SPAM _SCORE_ *****]
    required_score          5.0
    use_bayes               1
    bayes_auto_learn        1
    normalize_charset       1

# Включаем проверку DKIM
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::DKIM
score DKIM_SIGNED         1.000
score DKIM_VALID          1.000
score DKIM_VALID_AU       1.000
score DKIM_VALID_EF       1.000
score FSL_BULK_SIG        1.000
endif

# Проверка наличия HTML в письме
body HTML_MESSAGE         eval:check_for_html()
score HTML_MESSAGE        1.000

# Проверки на наличие HTML-тегов
body HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG eval:html_malformed()
score HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG 1.000
body MIME_HTML_ONLY       eval:html_tag_exists()
score MIME_HTML_ONLY      1.000

# Проверка на использование PYZOR
body PYZOR_CHECK           eval:check_pyzor()
score PYZOR_CHECK          1.000

# Проверка на наличие SPF в заголовке
header SPF_HELO_NONE       eval:check_for_spf_helo_none()
score SPF_HELO_NONE        1.000

# Проверка на PASS SPF
header SPF_PASS            eval:check_for_spf_pass()
score SPF_PASS             1.000

# Проверка блокировки по URI
body URIBL_BLOCKED         eval:check_uridnsbl('block.uribl.com')
score URIBL_BLOCKED        1.000

# Проверка на наличие в RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2
header RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2   eval:check_for_rcvd_in_msphike_h2()
score RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2    1.000
```

I'm restarting with the sudo service spamassassin restart command. I check the spamassassin --lint config, but nothing seems to change.